# Java script URL Loader and URL Varialbles

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have a URL to a text file which specifies what my menu controller is called and whether I am in debug mode etc....
eg. menudriver=MenuController.aspx&debug=true&webroot=https://somewebsite.com

Now what I would like to do is have this loaded into a variable in javascript then also each URL variable also saved into some array.

Once this has been done I have a menu that is dynamically populated according to what is received from a separate URL. Here is an as3 example:
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(WebRoot+fill+CallerURI+"?KR_ID="+Math.random());

This URL basically contains labels as well as URI for buttons in my menu.

How is this done is javascript?
I do have a completed  implementation in as3 but I am battling to find the javascript alternatives.

Comment: What is a `URLRequest`? or is that irrelevant?

Comment: Here is code that create query assoc array from Query String https://gist.github.com/jcubic/3004101 using jQuery but it can be done without it.

Comment: @jcubic I like that jquery function. Seems like it will do what I want. I was just wondering how someone would do it in javascript.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen URLRequest is a actionscript 3 built in function. No equivalent in javascript. Has to be implemented manually in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Reply to the comment, pure javascript solution

```
var query = (function() {
    function decode(string) {
        return decodeURIComponent(string.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var result = {};
    if (location.search) {
        location.search.substring(1).split('&').forEach(function(pair) {
            pair = pair.split('=');
            result[decode(pair[0])] = decode(pair[1]);
        });
    }
    return result;
})();
```

it use ECMAScript 5 function forEach, if you need to support browsers that don't support it, you can use [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).